# Unable to connect to Android device from Jenkins

Tags: android, python, jenkins, androidviewclient

So I used to call a MonkeyRunner script from within Jenkins to connect to a USB Android device and run some automated tests, however MonkeyRunner itself was rather unstable so I switched to the fantastic AndroidViewClient and ported my test script over to use this pure Python API.

The new Python script works fine when invoked independently from the shell however the goal is to call this script from Jenkins as a post build step.

The problem I have is the initial connection to the USB Android device. Script below is a snippet from the actual test script - this is the part that tests if a USB device is present and obtains it's serial number before connecting to the Android device. This works fine from the ubuntu shell however fails to connect when invoked from a Jenkins 'Execute Shell'.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Import Class Files

import re
import sys
import os
import time
import commands
import signal
import subprocess
import codecs

ubuntuHome = os.getenv('HOME')
sdkRootDefault = ubuntuHome + '/dev_env/ADT/sdk'
sdkRoot = os.getenv('ANDROID_SDK_ROOT',sdkRootDefault)
platformTools = sdkRoot + '/platform-tools'

# Find the attached devices
adbcmd = platformTools + "/./adb devices |grep -v attached |grep device |head -n 1 | cut  -f1"
p = subprocess.Popen(adbcmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
serialnoIn = (p.stdout.readline()).strip()

# No devices found then exit
if len(serialnoIn) == 0 or serialnoIn is None:
    print ("ERROR: No devices found")
    sys.exit(1)

print "INFO: Trying Connection to " + serialnoIn + "..."
```

From Ubuntu Shell the output is:

> INFO: Trying Connection to 3a005473...

From Jenkins 'Execute Shell' build step

> ERROR: No devices found

Interestingly when this same snippet was called from within the original MonkeyRunner script it worked fine. So I am thinking MonkeyRunner does some initial setup my Python script isn't doing? I am not enough of a Python expert to know how to configure USB devices. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the answer was simple really - it helps if jenkins can make use of the sdk tools and AndroidViewClient paths!

> sudo -Rm u:jenkins:rwx

...fixed it